# GPA calculation program

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to calculate the GPA and I'm supposed to allow the user to enter the information (course name, credit hours and letter grades) manually from the keyboard or read it from a file.  It works fine if I choose to read from file, but if choose to enter manually the program crashes when i finish entering the information.  I don't know what is the problem.  If you need an extra info please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i, count=0, credit[10], sumCredit = 0;
    double gpa, points[10], sumPoints = 0.0;
    char course[10][12], letter[10][2], fromfile;
    FILE *in, *out;

    printf("Do you want to read from a file? [Y/N]: ");
    scanf(" %c", &fromfile);
    if(fromfile == 'Y' || fromfile == 'y'){

        in = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
        if(in == NULL){
            printf("Error: Failed to open scores.txt\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        out = fopen("GPA.txt", "a");
        i=0;
        while(fscanf(in, "%s%d%s", course[i], &credit[i], letter[i]) != EOF){
            printf("%s\t%d\t%s\n", course[i], credit[i], letter[i]); 
            count++;
            i++;
            }

    }
    else if(fromfile == 'N' || fromfile == 'n'){

        for(i=0; strcmp(course[i-1], "0") ; i++){
             printf("Enter the name of the #%d course: ", i+1);
             scanf("%s", course[i]);
             if(strcmp(course[i], "0")){

             printf("Enter the credit hours for %s course: ", course[i] );
             scanf("%d", &credit[i]);

             printf("Enter your grade in %s course: ", course[i]);
             scanf(" %s", letter[i]);
             count++;}


        }
    }


     for(i=0; i<count; i++){

        if(!strcmp(letter[i], "a+")){
            points[i] = 4 * credit[i];
        }   
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "a"))
            points[i] = 3.75 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "b+"))
            points[i] = 3.5 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "b"))
            points[i] = 3 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "c+"))
            points[i] = 2.75 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "c"))
            points[i] = 2.5 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "d+"))
            points[i] = 2 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "d"))
            points[i] = 1.5 * credit[i];
        else if(!strcmp(letter[i], "f"))
            points[i] = 0 * credit[i];


     }
     fprintf(out, "\ncourse\thours\tletter grade\tpoints\n\n");
     printf("\ncourse\t\thours\tletter grade\tpoints\n\n");

     for(i=0; i < count; i++){
        fprintf(out, "%s\t\t%d%13s%15.2lf\n", course[i], credit[i], letter[i], points[i]);
        printf("%s\t\t%d%13s%15.2lf\n", course[i], credit[i], letter[i], points[i]);
        sumPoints += points[i];
        sumCredit += credit[i];

     }
     gpa = sumPoints / sumCredit;
     printf("your GPA = %0.2lf", gpa);
     fprintf(out, "your GPA = %0.2lf", gpa);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the quote formatting from your post

Comment: Also pick a programming language. C and C++ are not interchangeable.

Comment: What is `void readfile...`? It's not a function prototype, it's not a function implementation.

Comment: this line: `void readfile(FILE in, FILE out, char course[][12], char letter[][2], int credit[])` seems to be missing a trailing semicolon ';'

Comment: Pretty sure this could cause an issue `for(i=0; strcmp(course[i-1], "0")` since you would try to access `course[-1]` when you first try to enter the for loop when manually entering the information.  Are you sure it lets you manually enter all the information and then crashes and not that it crashes before entering the information?

Comment: @user3629249 you are 3 minutes too late for that, it's already been removed.

Comment: for readability and ease of documentation via such tools as `doxygen`, follow the axiom of `one statement per line and (at max) one variable declaration per statement.`

Comment: The indentation is not good and it's difficult to follow the blocks.  Also, naturally, debugger..........DCV.

Comment: @pstrjds yes it crashes when i enter 0 and hit enter. and i agree about the condtition  but i couldn't think of other way to do it

Comment: I identified the cause of the crash.  I voted to reopen.

Comment: @dbush thank you. can you point it out?

Comment: You're writing to `out` which is undefined.  Before manually reading values, set `out=stdout` and check the value of `fromfile` before calling `fclose(in);` and `fclose(out);`

Comment: thank you i just did it and it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the conditional of following line is wrong.

```
for(i=0; strcmp(course[i-1], "0") ; i++){
```

It should be:

```
for(i=0; strcmp(course[i-1], "0") == 0 ; i++){
                                  ^^^^
```

However, the more important error is that you will end up using `course[-1]` in the first iteration of the loop. That leads to undefined behavior.

You need to adjust your logic for the loop a little. Something like:

```
// Don't exceed the limit of the valid indices for course.
for (i=0; i < 10  ; i++)
{
   printf("Enter the name of the #%d course: ", i+1);
   scanf("%s", course[i]);

   // If the condition to stop is met, break out of the loop.
   if(strcmp(course[i], "0") == 0 )
   {
      break;
   }

   printf("Enter the credit hours for %s course: ", course[i] );
   scanf("%d", &credit[i]);

   printf("Enter your grade in %s course: ", course[i]);
   scanf(" %s", letter[i]);
   count++;
}
```

Comment: I would expect it would be very unhappy accessing `course[-1]` on the first loop iteration.

Comment: ..something easily spotted by the most trivial debugging effort:(